# Content type changes in sharepoint 2010 doesn't update document informaiton panel

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a doc library with content type, I can see the site columns from the content type whenever I create a new document based on the content type. It is working fine, recently I changed the required fields to not required. But I don't see that changed in the document information panel.

Could anyone please let me know how to tackle this.

Comment: Did you make sure to check "Yes" on "Update all list columns based on this column"?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Hi, how do you update your content type? Can you do this by code?